# write data into cache instead of disk on socket

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I know "`fileReader`" and "`fileWriter`" can read and write files from the disk transfer between the socket. However, I want to receive file from socket and write them to cache instead of  disk.

Is there a function that can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "cache"? RAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about keeping data in memory, you can use [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) for in-memory IO. You can then wrap these in an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) and [`InputStreamReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) respectively, for text-based IO.

(I'd actually suggest using `OutputStreamWriter` and `InputStreamReader` wrapped around `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` for file-based text IO too, as then you can specify the encoding you want to use.)

Comment: Is ByteArrayInputStream suitable for music or MB size file ?

Comment: @louis: It's just a stream view on top of a byte array - so as long as you're happy having a byte array that large in memory, it's fine.